# Starting two intents one after another

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I'm trying to start two calendar intents one followed by another when a button is clicked but it isn't working.

Code:

```
        Intent calIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        calIntent1.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");   
        calIntent1.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "TITLE");

        GregorianCalendar calDate1 = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, min);
        calIntent1.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false);
        calIntent1.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
        calDate1.getTimeInMillis());
        calIntent1.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
        calDate1.getTimeInMillis()+2*60*60*1000);

        Intent calIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        calIntent2.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");   
        calIntent2.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "TITLE2");

        GregorianCalendar calDate2 = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, min);
        calIntent2.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false);
        calIntent2.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
        calDate2.getTimeInMillis());
        calIntent2.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
        calDate2.getTimeInMillis()+2*60*60*1000);

        startActivity(calIntent2); startActivity(calIntent1);
```

Any idea why is not working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain **completely and precisely** what "not working" means. Your code as written will start two activities, which will stack on top of each other.

Comment: Means that it only starts the first activity but not the second one

Comment: I just found out that this code is working ok with google calendar app for example; but it isn't working with samsung calendar app

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onActivityResult method** for this. You will start 1 intent and wait for it's result. And then you can start your second intent. Some example code for you :

```
package **yourpackagename**;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;

public class TwoIntentClass extends Activity {

public static final int REQUEST_FIRST_INTENT = 10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // call your method here
    yourMethodName(2014, 9, 10, 5, 20);

}

public void yourMethodName(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min) {
    Intent calIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    calIntent1.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    calIntent1.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "TITLE");

    GregorianCalendar calDate1 = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, min);
    calIntent1.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false);
    calIntent1.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, calDate1.getTimeInMillis());
    calIntent1.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, calDate1.getTimeInMillis() + 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    startActivityForResult(calIntent1, REQUEST_FIRST_INTENT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // if this is true, this means your first intent finished. So you can start your second intent
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_FIRST_INTENT) {

        Intent calIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        calIntent2.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        calIntent2.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "TITLE2");

        GregorianCalendar calDate2 = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, min);
        calIntent2.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false);
        calIntent2.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, calDate2.getTimeInMillis());
        calIntent2.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, calDate2.getTimeInMillis() + 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        startActivity(calIntent2);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This could solve my issue, I'll try in a while and tell you about, thanks

Comment: It isn't working with the samsung calendar :S As I understood, I should initialize "REQUEST_FIRST_INTENT" as an int with any value, shouldn't I?

Comment: I already initialized RQEUEST_FIRST_INTENT at my code. Check the code. And this is your choice, so you can give any value to request flag. I didn't try this code at samsung calendar. If that gives error, write it your post.

Comment: I've checked the code with some Log's: the problem is that `startActivity(calIntent2);` is not being shown when it is called